# Calculating the angle of a vector

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to total this up because im not sure, in order to find the angle. I'll greatly appreciate it. I need to know very soon! Exam tomorrow!

Comment: Now simplify the top and bottom.

Comment: Just calculate this cosine...

Comment: yeah so i get 2/squareroot 289 squareroot 578... now what

Comment: sqrt(289)=17. Now start to simplify the other surd.

Comment: You should get $cos(\theta)=289/\sqrt{289}\sqrt{578}$. Now $289/\sqrt{289}\sqrt{578}=\sqrt{289}/\sqrt{578}$. Note that $578=2\times 289$

Comment: **Edward ffitch** has shown you that $ \ \cos \theta \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{289}}{\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{289}} \ $ . What does that reduce to?  If you then rationalize the denominator, you'll find the result on your table...

Comment: BUMP, guys i still don't understand this and my test is in 2 hours! could someone please help @RecklessReckoner

Comment: @Edwardffitch i still need help with this question sorry to be a pain!

Comment: @user120282: What is your problem? Asking a *specific* question rather than "I don't understand!" often leads to better results. Did you notice that you were told that you *shouldn't* have gotten "$2 / (\sqrt{289} \sqrt{578})$? Have you tried recomputing it? What have you done with everything that was said to you after that?

Comment: @user120282: Without actually trying to do the problem, can you describe how you think the problem should be done?

Answer (score 0):

For two vectors written as

$$ u \ = \ \left( \begin{array}{c} u_x \\ u_y \end{array} \right) \ \ \text{and} \ \ v \ = \ \left( \begin{array}{c} v_x \\ v_y \end{array} \right) \ \ ,
 $$

the cosine of the angle between the vectors is given by

$$ \ \cos \theta \ = \  \frac{u_x \cdot v_x \ + \ u_y \cdot v_y}{(\sqrt{u_x^2 + u_y^2}) \ \cdot \ (\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2})} \ \ .$$

This is the same as **Vishwa Iyer**'s answer, but written out in terms of the vector components.  This is the formula being used in the example you posted.